# Price Display Decimal Formatting Problems

Tags: price

I have been working on a site and am having some issues with the pricing display. The currency I am working in is Indonesian Rupiah.

The Indonesia currency that we use would need to display like the following options

Rp89,000
Rp100,000
Rp1,200,000
Rp11,500,000

Am not sure what I have done but once I go over 999,999 the currency displays like this Rp1.500.000,000. Under 999,999 it displays correctly. (this is a sample of one that is displaying in correctly http://www.cellar2door.com/index.php/rosemount-estate-diamond-label-shiraz-2010.html)

Could anyone point me in the right direction as to what I can edit to fix this? The site is nearly finished and this is the only problem I currently have.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i have faced the same problem in magento. I have used easy & simple extension  for all related currency.

It is free of coast.

Url:http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/et-currency-manager.html

Comment: Thanks for that. Sorry for a really dumb question but I am very very new to Mageneto. I have installed the currency manager but now it is installed where do I go to use it?

Comment: Its ok found it now in the currency set up tab

Comment: Thanks keshav that has solved the problem straight away. All working well now. Just need to re enter the prics in the products and am a very happy chappy.